# <script src="filename.js"></script> works locally, not over network

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a web page that originally had embedded JavaScript within a script section, and it worked fine when served up with a simple http server.

I now want to put my JavaScript, which manipulates SVG elements, in separate files, and as a first try, I put it all in a singe .js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Some Graphics With SVG</title>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
    <style>
        #svgContainer {
            width:  2188px;
            height: 1312px;
            background-color: "white";
        }
    </style>
<script src="all.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="resagui()">
    <div id="svgContainer"></div>
</body>
```

I should note that the JavaScript function resagui appears at the top of all.js:

```
function resagui() {
   ...
}
```

Everything works great when I test this locally and view the page with file:///...  from my browser.  But when I try http://ipaddress:port it does not work.

I know that this is not a network issue, as the html file with embedded JavaScript works fine when I try http://ipaddress:port

My Firefox browser console provides two errors:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
and
ReferenceError: resagui is not defined

The html looks well formed, and there is no '<' character in my .js file.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Jay

Comment: Do you have "all.js" in the root of your website?

Comment: Is the `all.js` file in the proper location on the server?

Comment: Just FYI, the `title` and `meta` tags go inside of the `head` tag.

Comment: all.js is in the same directory as index.html, but not in the root directory.  This is not a website as much as a graphical description, using SVG, generated by an application.  Is there a way to re-define the "root" directory, perhaps with an environment variable (this is on Linux)?

Comment: One good trick with Firefox for issues like this. View source.  Find the link in your script src and click it.  See what comes up.  Usually it's going to be a 404 ;)

Comment: I clicked the link to the source script and nothing came up.  btw, I realize that the src attribute is technically a URL, but even file:///fullpathname does not work.

Comment: Hi, folks.  This all started working when I switched from one trivial webserver to another.  Old:

while true; do { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; cat index.html; } | nc -l 8081; done

New:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081